# Process Multiple XML Files from Folder

Tags: xml, c#-4.0

I am working in C#.Net. I am having a XML File. From that i will get the data and then i process it. Bydefault that XML will be in a folder and i will use that. Here is my code..

```
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
xDoc.Load(System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Test.xml"));
--My Process Starts Here.....
```

In the same folder i will have multiple XML Files.(i.e) Test.XML,Test1.XML,Test2.XML etc... I want to process all the XML Files. Each and every time i cant able to change the file name in my source code. I thought of passing the file name itself as a parameter. I want to know whether this is correct. Or else any other way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried with this..Now i can able to access all the XML Files.

```
        XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
        string path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
        foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.xml"))
        {
          xDoc.Load(System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), file));
          string strpath = xDoc.BaseURI;
        }
```